# What CSP child iframe inherits from its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, content-security-policy

I have a webpage (say origin=A) that has an iframe embedded in it which loads from a different domain (say B). B loads bunch scripts from different domains (various CDNs). My webpage A sets pretty strict CSP like:

> default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; frame-src B

B doesn't set any CSP headers.

Now I would expect the child frame, B, to inherit the CSP rules of A and trying to access various CDNs should be a violation of its CSP because of script-src 'self' but to my surprise, it works smoothly.

So my question is:
How CSP is inherited by child iframes ? Does it depend on its parent frame's CSP if CSP for iframe is not mentioned ? If yes, how ? Is there any documentation somewhere about it, I couldn't find anything specific that would explain the situation above.

Is there a way I can debug the CSP inherited by child iframes ? From Chrome's debugger or FF's debugger - by selecting the iframe and then CSP for the iframe would show up ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How CSP is inherited by child iframes?

It’s not — not in the common case (the “loads from a different domain” case in the question).

But there are other ways to populate `iframe`, and CSP works different for those (see below).

> Does it depend on its parent frame's CSP if CSP for iframe is not mentioned?

No, it doesn’t for the common case (the “loads from a different domain” case in the question).

> Is there any documentation somewhere about it

Yes, see the [*Policy applicability* section of the CSP2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#which-policy-applies), which says this:

> **Embedded Contexts**: Any resource included via `iframe`, `object`, or `embed`.
>
> Unless the embedded resource is a globally unique identifier (or a `srcdoc` iframe), the embedded resource is controlled by the policy delivered with the resource. If the embedded resource is a globally unique identifier or `srcdoc` iframe, it inherits the policy of the context creating it.

A “globally unique identifier” is something with a `data:` URL or other kind of URL that’s not a hierarchical URL such an `https`/`http` URL.

So the common case (“loads from a different domain” in the question) is a “embedded resource is controlled by the policy delivered with the resource” case—that is, it doesn’t inherit.

In contrast, if the `iframe` is a `srcdoc` iframe, the case is very different and [the spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#processing-model-iframe-srcdoc):

> Whenever a user agent creates an `iframe srcdoc` document in a browsing context nested in the protected resource, if the user agent is enforcing any policies for the protected resource, the user agent MUST enforce those policies on the `iframe srcdoc` document as well.

That is a `srcdoc` iframe *does* inherit its parent’s CSP policy.

Comment: hmm, so given domain B doesn't have any CSP headers, what will be the default policy values for it ? Does it differ from browser to browser ? Is there some way to know it - like from the browser console or something ?

Comment: If domain B doesn’t have any CSP headers, then the browser applies no CSP restrictions and allows everything that would otherwise be allowed—scripts/stylesheets from anywhere, at any URL, inline scripts/stylesheets, etc.—as well as allowing all non-hierarchical schemes that browsers normally allow. That doesn’t differ from browser to browser. If you want to consider in terms of being a CSP “default policy”, then it basically corresponds to something like `default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-dynamic' data: filesystem: about: blob: ws: wss:`

Comment: I'm doing some tests and it seems to me like Edge is inheriting frame-src/child-src on embedded iframes no matter what. Chrome does not.