# Enabling CSP's unsafe-eval in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, eval, content-security-policy

I need to embed Vega-js library (a heavy user of `new Function()` evals) into a site with the locked down CSP (no eval allowed). I have been exploring two options, and would love feedback on the best path to take:

- `nonce` - serve the eval-using script via the `nonce` directive, hoping that eval() error will not be triggered. This assumption might not be correct - I'm still trying to comprehend `nonce` limitations.
- place Vega graph in an `<iframe sandbox='allow-scripts'>...</>`, and communicate with it via messages. I don't know if it is possible for an `<iframe>` on a locked down site to have a more lax security settings (allow evals) than its parent.

Comment: The second option should currently be possible using `postMessage`.

Comment: You say, “I need to embed Vega-js library (a heavy user of `new Function()` evals) into a site with the locked down CSP (no eval allowed)” but then one of the options you say you’re considering is to add use of `nonce`. If by “locked down” you mean you can’t change the policy at all, then it’s unclear how you’d plan to adjust it to include a `nonce` source…

Comment: @sideshowbarker I can adjust the site's policy (e.g. add a `nonce`), but the security engineers do not want to allow `eval` for all of the site. They are ok to allow it for a specific library.

Comment: Ah OK. Well then it definitely seems like the `<iframe>` approach you describe may be the only practical option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if it is possible for an `<iframe>` on a locked down site to have a more lax security settings (allow evals) than its parent.

It is actually possible for the `<iframe>` to have a more-lax CSP policy that its parent. Unless it’s an `<iframe srcdoc=…>`, it inherits nothing from the CSP policy of the parent and has no relationship to the parent CSP policy at all.

See the answer at *[What CSP child iframe inherits from its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236626/what-csp-child-iframe-inherits-from-its-parent/43237443#43237443)* and the section of the CSP spec at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#which-policy-applies that covers *“Any resource included via `iframe`, `object`, or `embed`”*.

> `nonce` - serve the eval-using script via the `nonce` directive, hoping that eval() error will not be triggered. This assumption might not be correct - I'm still trying to comprehend `nonce` limitations.

See the answer at *[What’s the purpose of the HTML "nonce" attribute for script and style elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922784/what-s-the-purpose-of-the-html-nonce-attribute-for-script-and-style-elements/42924000#42924000)* for a detailed explanation about how `nonce` works.

But even if you are use `nonce` to “whitelist” a particular script, that’s not going to allow use of `eval` by that script. With a CSP policy in place, the only way to allow use of  `eval` is to specify `'unsafe-eval'`. And if you specify that, it will allow use of `eval` by all scripts the document embeds — there’s no way to only allow use of `eval` by  particular scripts but not by others.